# W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have done all the steps.

1. `pip` install tensorflow
2. creating environment for it
3. installing cuda
4. installing VS code

everything...
BUT this issue is occuring in my system-

```
2021-09-12 07:11:02.364108: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-09-12 07:11:02.364481: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

SOMEONE PLEASE HELP!!!!!

Comment: does this help? `pip install tf-nightly`